# How to wait for receiving data from socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout, wait

I create wait_for_data function in c++ but doesn't work correctly.

In below code numReady always is true; why ?

```
struct timeval selTimeout;
selTimeout.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;
selTimeout.tv_usec = (timeout % 1000) * 1000;
fd_set readSet;
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(sock, &readSet);

int numReady = select(sock + 1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &selTimeout);
if (numReady>0) {
// reading data here
} else {
//finish
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is not working. This is a question/answer site and not we won't debug your code.

Comment: thank you mkaes I change question.

I find similar to this code in synapse freepascal class (TTCPBlockingSocket) and try to translate it to c++ but I don't know why this code not work in cpp ?

Comment: And why would you expect something else. If select returns with a value greater than zero, there are bits set in the `fd_set` structs. So in your case your socket is ready to read.

Comment: that's right but when calling read function to read data from socket doesn't receive any data and application freeze until client close socket for send more data.

Comment: Assuming you are on linux. It is possible that a socket will block even if select reported it readiness. To avoid such a blocking you should use `O_NONBLOCK` on the socket. Read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

Comment: thank you mkaes you're right I'm in linux and your answer solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a socket will block even if select reported it readiness. To avoid such a blocking you should use `O_NONBLOCK` on the socket. Read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) – mkaes